# Query for getting OrderLineItems in Shopware 6 fails due to missing column 'order_line_item.order.order_line_item_version_id'

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to get all OrderLineItems in Shopware 6.4.18.1, that are a product of a certain manufacturer and:

- paid for (if prepayment was used)
- or either:

  - paid partially
  - payment in progress
  - payment open

The following code:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyBundle\App\Query\OrderLineItem;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\PrePayment;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityCollection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\AndFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\NorFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\OrFilter;

class OrderLineItemQuery
{
    public const PAID_STATE = 'paid';
    public const PAID_PARTIALLY_STATE = 'paid_partially';
    public const IN_PROGRESS_STATE = 'in_progress';
    public const OPEN_STATE = 'open';

    protected EntityRepository $orderLineItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepository $orderLineItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderLineItemRepository = $orderLineItemRepository;
    }

    public function getOrderLineItemsByManufacturer(string $manufacturerId): EntityCollection
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();

        // default associations needed for following procedures
        $criteria->addAssociations([
            'order.deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country',
            'order.deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.salutation',
            'order.orderCustomer.customer.salutation',
            'order.salesChannel',
            'order.transactions.stateMachineState',
            'order.transactions.paymentMethod',
            'product.manufacturer',
        ]);

        $criteria->addFilter(
            // only take manufacturer products
            new EqualsFilter('product.manufacturer.id', $manufacturerId),
            // exclude unpaid prepayment orders
            new OrFilter([
                new EqualsFilter('order.transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::PAID_STATE),
                // removing the filters inside here fixes the problem
                new AndFilter([
                    new NorFilter([
                        new EqualsFilter('order.transactions.paymentMethod.handlerIdentifier', PrePayment::class),
                    ]),
                    new OrFilter([
                        new EqualsFilter('order.transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::PAID_PARTIALLY_STATE),
                        new EqualsFilter('order.transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::IN_PROGRESS_STATE),
                        new EqualsFilter('order.transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::OPEN_STATE),
                    ]),
                ]),
            ])
        );

        return $this->orderLineItemRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->getEntities();
    }
}
```

But it only returns the Error:

> In Exception.php line 18:
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_line_item.order.order_line_item_version_id' in 'field list'

Removing everything inside the `AndFilter` seems to remove the error, but I need to exclude the OrderLineItems from orders where prepayment was choosen as payment method, but not yet paid.

How should I change the query to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here might be a circular reference. Since you're querying mostly associations of the order, I'd recommend basing your query on the `order` table by using `order.repository` instead. By passively adding the `lineItems` association, you can then iterate over the `OrderEntity` instances and collect all corresponding line items by calling `getLineItems()`.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();

// default associations needed for following procedures
$criteria->addAssociations([
    'deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country',
    'deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.salutation',
    'orderCustomer.customer.salutation',
    'salesChannel',
    'transactions.stateMachineState',
    'transactions.paymentMethod',
]);

/**
 * Get an association `lineItems`. (is added by calling the getter as well)
 * Add a filter specifically for that association.
 * Optionally, if you need `product` and `manufacturer` data, 
 * add them as additional associations.
 */
$criteria->getAssociation('lineItems')
    ->addFilter(
        new EqualsFilter('product.manufacturer.id', $manufacturerId)
    )
    ->addAssociation('product.manufacturer');

$criteria->addFilter(
    new OrFilter([
        new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::PAID_STATE),
        new AndFilter([
            new NorFilter([
                new EqualsFilter('transactions.paymentMethod.handlerIdentifier', PrePayment::class),
            ]),
            new OrFilter([
                new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::PAID_PARTIALLY_STATE),
                new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::IN_PROGRESS_STATE),
                new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.technicalName', self::OPEN_STATE),
            ]),
        ]),
    ])
);

$orders = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->getEntities();

$lineItems = new OrderLineItemCollection();
/** @var OrderEntity $order */
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $lineItems->merge($order->getLineItems());
}

return $lineItems;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but if I understand correctly, if an order contains 2 products, one from the requested manufacturer, and the other one from another manufacturer, both products will still be merged in `$lineItems`, correct?

Comment: No, the `OrderLineItemCollection` retrieved by calling `getLineItems()` should then only include the line items associated with the product from the one manufacturer. The `Criteria` is turned into a SQL query with a chain of joins, starting from the `order_line_item` records up to the `manufacturer` table. The joined tables are then used in the `WHERE` statement. So no unselected value should be included in the final result. BTW, you may want to use `lineItems.product.manufacturerId` instead, one less join ;)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to detect the circular reference or throw an early exception? From the above code used, I don't see one.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a guess of mine. It seems a little weird and I haven't seen that yet, where it tries to use a version field of one entity on an entirely different one.  I thought this could happen if you have an association that is like two times remove from the source, which then has an association back on the source, maybe being autoloaded or something. This is a rather hefty query, so it's hard to say where this could happen without investigating further.

Comment: Sadly, it includes the products that are not from the given manufacturer. I will add a check before the `->merge()`

Comment: My bad. I forgot that you have to apply filters to the actual association to reduce the corresponding collection. I updated my answer. This would be preferable performance wise.